# Partial Highlight of a JOptionPan text

Tags: java, swing, highlight, joptionpane

[image]

When I lunch my JOptionPan, the above image is what I get.
I'd like to have only the part "*@127.0.0.1*" highlighted, without the "*root*" part.
This is the code I'm using:

```
            JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, msg
                ,"Connection à l'"+this.nom, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, loginHistory);
```

Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DefaultHighlighter that comes with your JTextArea. For e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);

      textArea.setText("This is a text");

      Highlighter highlighter = textArea.getHighlighter();
      HighlightPainter painter = 
             new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.pink);
      int p0 = text.indexOf("is");
      int p1 = p0 + "is".length();
      highlighter.addHighlight(p0, p1, painter );

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JScrollPane(textArea));          
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using a `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)` instead of a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(...)`:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public final class PartialHighlightTest {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override public void run() {
        createAndShowGUI();
      }
    });
  }
  public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    String msg = "<html>Veuillez: <font color=green>root<font color=red>@adresse";
    String loginHistory = "root@127.0.0.1";
    //JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    //  null, msg, "title", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, null, loginHistory);

    Box box = Box.createVerticalBox();
    box.add(new JLabel(msg));
    JTextField textField = new JTextField();
    textField.addAncestorListener(new AncestorListener() {
      @Override public void ancestorAdded(AncestorEvent e) {
        JTextField field = (JTextField) e.getComponent();
        field.requestFocusInWindow();
        String t = field.getText();
        field.select(t.indexOf("@"), t.length());
      }
      @Override public void ancestorMoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
      @Override public void ancestorRemoved(AncestorEvent e) {}
    });
    box.add(textField);
    textField.setText(loginHistory);
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(
      null, box, "title",
      JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION,
      JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println(textField.getText());
  }
}
```